# How to assign a string?

Tags: python

I have this command for wake on the system `os.system('sudo sh -c "echo date \'+%s\' -d \'+ 24 hours\' > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"')`. After executing this command i just open wakealaram file. It is empty, nothing is written.

1. Why is it empty, shouldn't it write some date?
2. How to give a manual date to wakealaram instead of system date + 24 hours?
   eg:date = "2147472000"

Would `os.system('sudo sh -c "echo date > /sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm"')` work?

Comment: did you try this at the bash prompt? what happened? are you catching errors in your python script? logging them? what do they say?

Comment: You have [a lot of questions with no accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1268804/viswa?tab=questions&sort=newest). You should [accept some answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/157794). This will give others incentive to actually answer your questions.

Comment: [This page](http://ragsagar.wordpress.com/2011/08/15/how-to-automatically-wake-up-your-computer-at-a-particular-time-resume-by-rtc-alarm-in-arch-linux/) seems to have a detailed guide on how to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: Obviously, you don't want answers any longer. Otherwise, you would finally start to accept answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
os.system("sudo date >/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm")
```